# Quotation Mark Lost in Array

Tags: ios, arrays, string, swift

I have multiple strings in an array. They each already contain a quotation mark but I want to add another `"` to each string's end. This is how I do it:

```
for var str in coordinates {
    str += "\""
    print(str)
}
print(coordinates[0])
```

`print(str)` prints `My"String"` which is how it should be.
But `print(coordinates[0]` prints `My"String`

How come? Is this just how the strings are displayed but the actual string contains the `"`?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `for var` the `var` is only for the current scope inside the loop.

It's not a reference to the strings in the array, it's a copy (value).

You *could* mutate the existing strings in the array but the Swifty way of doing this is to create a new one, with `map` for example:

```
let result = coordinates.map { str in return str + "\"" }
```

Short version:

```
let result = coordinates.map { $0 + "\"" }
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for :)